# Angularjs, Promises not well written

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this html code

```
<body ng-app="myModule">
    <div ng-controller="myController">{{text}}</div>
</body>
```

And this js code

var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);

```
myModule.controller('myController', ['$scope', 'Database', function($scope, Database) {
    Database.first()
        .then($scope.text = 'first')
        .then(Database.second())
        .then($scope.text = 'second')
        .then(Database.third())
        .then($scope.text = 'third');
}]);

myModule.factory('Database', ['$window', '$q', function($window, $q) {
    return {
        first: function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            setTimeout(function() {deferred.resolve();alert('ei')},4000);
            return deferred.promise;
        },
        second: function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            setTimeout(function() {deferred.resolve()},4000);
            return deferred.promise;
        },
        third: function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            setTimeout(function() {deferred.resolve()},4000);
            return deferred.promise;
        },
    }
}]);
```

(found here http://jsfiddle.net/C5gJr/44/)

Then I am wondering why the deferred is resolved without waiting the time I ask. I am using this structure to not to start a function before the other is finished and it is working like this one (here using the setTimeout).

Another (secondary) question

```
        .then($scope.text = 'first')
        .then(Database.second())
```

Why when I am just filling a variable, the .then function still works??

Thanks in advance :)

Gerard

Comment: I can really recommend this talk by Christian Lilley on promises in Angular: [http://youtu.be/XcRdO5QVlqE](http://youtu.be/XcRdO5QVlqE)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake is that you use `then` wrong. It should be:

```
Database.first()
.then(function() {
    $scope.text = 'first';
})
.then(function() {
    return Database.second();
})
.then(function() {
    $scope.text = 'second'
})
.then(function() {
    return Database.third()
})
.then(function() {
    $scope.text = 'third'
});
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/NGYPiLdUGBzzvVHFFBWy?p=preview

One more time. This

```
.then($scope.text = 'first')
```

is not correct. `then` expects you to pass a function in it. So it should be:

```
.then(function() {
    $scope.text = 'first'
})
```

Comment: I see. But, then why is it necessary with Database.second() and Database.third()? They are already functions.

Comment: Because `Database.third()` is not a function. It's promise object (result of execution). And you want `then` to return promise in proper moment. But instead you call it immediately (due to `()`), so `then` never get a change to return proper  promise.

Comment: But I thought that "then" was a function provided by the promise object. But I understand that it is not? Is there any documentation about the "then"? In other words, why it can work with the scope.text statement?

Comment: Consider this: `then(callback)`. When this code is executed callback is pushed into the stack array. Those callbacks will be executed one by one in correct order when promise is resolved. When you write `then($scope.text = 'first')` there is no callback, because it's the same as `then('first')`, this resolve immediately.

Comment: got it, and I have applied it to my code and it works perfectly :) Thanks a lot for your time!